# Sprite Kit Physics: NSArray Objects

Tags: nsarray, sprite-kit

Hi I have the below code with multiple items in an array but my concern is how can I apply physics property on each array objects? I meant the physics properties in Sprite kit.

```
- (void) ItemMakerEnemy {
    myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"water", @"door", @"car", @"mypapers", nil];

    NSUInteger arraypicker = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    for (int i=0; i < arraypicker; ++i) {
        NSString *d1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        sprites = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:d1];
        sprites.xScale = 0.22;
        sprites.yScale = 0.22;
        sprites.position = CGPointMake(ScalarRandomRange(sprites.size.width/2 + sprites.size.height, 200), self.size.height*2);

        [self addChild:sprites];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another array which specifies the physics body. 
For example if you are using level editors like Tiled it is common to have different layers. First layer specifies the images (tiles), second layer if the elements reacts on collisions, ...

Another possibility is to implement a big if then else statement which adds the physics properties depending on the elements of your array